# adding quantity on archive page wordpress fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i tried to add a quantity field to a wordpress webshop i'm building.
The idea is that customers can add products to their cart on the archive page instead of the product page.

i installed the plugin: WooCommerce Quantity Increment and added some code i found on google that uses ajax instead of a page refresh.(i'm not familiar with jQuery..)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.input-text.qty', 'ul.products').on('input', function() {
        console.log("piep");
        console.log(this);
        $(this).closest('.winkelmandje').find('.add_to_cart_button').data('quantity', $(this).val());
    });
    $('.plus', 'ul.products').click( function() {
        var counter = 1;
        console.log(+$('.input-text.qty').val() + 1);
        //$('.input-text.qty').val(quantity++);;
        $('.input-text.qty').closest('.winkelmandje').find('.add_to_cart_button').data('quantity', +$('.input-text.qty').val() + 1);
    });
});
```

i tried to implement everything the right way. at first i thought it worked well. But if you add six of the same products to your cart. And after that you try to add 10 pieces of another product. it only adds six of that other product too..

I'm staring at it for 2 days now and can't figure it out. Hope you guys can help me out!

A working version of the webshop: http://vandouglashout.com/winkel

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking for one `val()`, so it will only see the first quantity from any input. Your code assumes there will be only one element that matches. If you loop through `.input-text.qty` elements, you should be able to get the value from each and could make an associative array of products and their selected quantities.